# How to determine how many unique values are in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing lists that look something like this:

```
['33', '34', '34', '34', '35', '35', '36', '36', '38']
['34', '37', '38']
['33', '33', '35', '35', '38', '38']
```

I'm trying to get the number of unique values for each of these lists automatically (i.e. the third list would have a value of 3).

How should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print len(set([1,1,2,2,3,3]))
```

is that what you are looking for?

`set`s are just like lists ... except they only contain unique elements, and they have no order

Answer (score 0):

Build a set and then get its length:

```
print len(set(yourlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

`len(set(x))` is the number of unique elements in collection `x`.

So for that dictionary:

```
d
Out[16]: 
{'a': ['33', '34', '34', '34', '35', '35', '36', '36', '38'],
 'b': ['34', '37', '38'],
 'c': ['33', '33', '35', '35', '38', '38']}
```

You'd have

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(k,len(set(v))))

a: 5
c: 3
b: 3
```

python 3 syntax.